# how do I use auto complete return on the next auto complete

Tags: jquery

I have categories and sub categories all on the same table.

For example;

catid = 1
parentid = 0
name = UCLA

catid = 2
parentid = 1
name = business faculty

catid = 3
parentid = 2
name = marketing major

I use auto complete to get university names for university field.

Now, I want the faculty field but only to load university's faculties.

How can I the `UniversityID` return on the next field?

Thanks!

```
    $( ".signup-form input[name='COMMUNITY']").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "/content/signup/index.cs.asp?Process=CheckEmail&PARENTID=0&COMMUNITY=" + request.term,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.CheckEmail, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.Name,
                    value: item.Name,
                    emailURL: item.emailURL,
                    UniversityID: item.UniversityID
                }
                }));
            }
            });
        },
    $( ".signup-form input[name='COMMUNITY']").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "/content/signup/index.cs.asp?Process=CheckEmail&PARENTID=????&COMMUNITY=" + request.term,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.CheckEmail, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.Name,
                    value: item.Name,
                    emailURL: item.emailURL,
                    FacultyID: item.FacultyID
                }
                }));
            }
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the selected Item by `$("input").data("autocomplete").selectedItem`.

so your url for the second autocomplete could be `"/content/signup/index.cs.asp?Process=CheckEmail&PARENTID=" + $("input#university").data("autocomplete").selectedItem.UniversityId + "&COMMUNITY=" + request.term`

#### edit

maybe you should first check if there is a selected value before using it:

```
var uniID = $("input#university").data("autocomplete").selectedItem;
uniID = uniID && uniID.UniversityId || 0;
$.ajax({
  url : "/content/signup/index.cs.asp?Process=CheckEmail&PARENTID="+uniID+"&COMMUNITY=" + request.term,
  ....
})
```

Comment: lordvlad, can we chat about it sometime?

Comment: i've opened a chat room, feel free to join. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29087/how-do-i-use-auto-complete-return-on-the-next-auto-complete